# Run-time error '-2147352567(80020009)': cannot parse condition. Error at "SQL="urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"..."

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to modifying existing code for my requirement with my limited knowledge. I've customized the code based on Dmitry suggessions, which results in saving my attachments to destination folder in my computer. but getting below error for the variable dates using startdate and enddate string

Run-time error '-2147352567(80020009)':

cannot parse condition. Error at "SQL="urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"...".

Error happening exactly at Set myRestrictItems = myItems.Restrict(Filter)

but it works fine with direct dates

Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                               Chr(34) & " >= '01/01/2017' And " & _
                               Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                               Chr(34) & " < '28/07/2018'"

```
Sub Extract()

Dim valid As Boolean: valid = True
Dim oShell As Object
Dim Filter As String
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myRestrictItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim StartDate, EndDate As String

Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set myFolder = myNamespace.PickFolder

Set myItems = myFolder.Items

StartDate = InputBox("Enter the Start Date in dd/mm/yyyy format", vbOKOnly)
EndDate = InputBox("Enter the End Date in dd/mm/yyyy format", vbOKOnly)

Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
Chr(34) & " >= " & StartDate & _
Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
Chr(34) & " <= " & EndDate & ""


Set myRestrictItems = myItems.Restrict(Filter)

strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)

strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\Attachments\"

For i = myRestrictItems.Count To 1 Step -1

Set myItem = myRestrictItems(i)

    For Each oAttachment In myItem.Attachments

        oAttachment.SaveAsFile strFolderpath & oAttachment.FileName

    Next

   Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Add Sourcecode in Code Block

Answer (score 1):

Why are you looping over *all* items in the destination folder on *each* iteration in the source folder? Save the attachments first, then move the item

```
For i = myRestrictItems.Count To 1 Step -1
   set myItem = myRestrictItems(i)
   for each oAttachment in myItem.Attachments
     oAttachment.SaveAsFile objDestinationFolder & oAttachment.FileName
   next
   myItem.Move myDestFolder
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I've updated the VBA code with the above recommendations, but it doesn't save attachments but move my emails to folder named "Filtered" in mailbox. Also, i need to input dates using a string StartDate and EndDate, it get my input but it doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for the the above runtime error, the date pickedup as a string, which I have converted again into date format and then input into values have fixed the error message. Here is the final code.

```
Sub Extract()

Dim valid As Boolean: valid = True
Dim oShell As Object
Dim Filter As String
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myRestrictItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim StartDate, EndDate As String


Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set myFolder = myNamespace.PickFolder

Set myItems = myFolder.Items

StartDate = InputBox("Enter the Start Date in dd/mm/yyyy format", vbOKOnly)
EndDate = InputBox("Enter the End Date in dd/mm/yyyy format", vbOKOnly)

StartDate = "'" & Format(StartDate, "Short Date") & "'"
EndDate = "'" & Format(EndDate, "Short Date") & "'"

eFilter = "@SQL= (urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived >= " & StartDate & _
      " And urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived <= " & EndDate & ")"


Set myRestrictItems = myItems.Restrict(eFilter)

strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)

strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\Attachments\"

For i = myRestrictItems.Count To 1 Step -1

Set myItem = myRestrictItems(i)

    For Each oAttachment In myItem.Attachments

            oAttachment.SaveAsFile strFolderpath & Format(i, "000#") & "_" & oAttachment.FileName
        Next
    Next

 End Sub
```